# Can I change a transaction description in Electrum while the transaction is still unconfirmed?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, electrum

I inserted a wrong description into a transaction made with Electrum per mistake, so I double clicked the description in and changed it to another value, while it was unconfirmed. My question is, will this last (final) value be visible once it is confirmed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descriptions are a feature of the electrum wallet, and do not appear on the Bitcoin chain - someone using another wallet (or even you restoring the keys into another electrum wallet) will not see the description.

Comment: So i must always mention the right description at the moment of the transaction itself?

Comment: The description has nothing to do with the transaction - it is only for your personal records, it doesn't matter if you leave it blank, put in something random, or put in what you actually wanted to. It has no effect on the transaction and its completion,